# Store polyline coordinates in xml resource

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, maps

I am drawing polylines with a lot of points (I got them with snap to road). Right now my code looks like this:

```
 PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
            .add(new LatLng(47.183845335746227, 18.408230864565329))
            .add(new LatLng(47.1835746, 18.4079741))
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .add(new LatLng(47.183364399999995, 18.4078905));
rectOptions.color(Color.RED);
mMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```

I would like to store these coordinates in an xml file in res/values/coordinates and I have several polylines, so I would like to store their coordinates in several files. How can I do that?

Comment: You can use the `PolyUtil.encode` method from the [Google Maps Android API utility library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/) to encode a sequence of `LatLng`s into an encoded path `String`

Comment: Dont reinvent the wheel. Make .gpx files.